# What is this persistent in-call/in-progress bar called when a mobile app is backgrounded (iOS and Android)?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio

At least for iOS, apps like Spotify, Hangouts, and Google Maps have a way of showing that they're still active when in the background (when you temporarily leave them to check a different app, etc.). This typically appears as a thicker status bar in iOS.

[image: screenshot showing example of such a bar]

Other variants:

[image]

What is this bar called, and is this possible to implement for Android? I have a video chat app (in both Google Play and App Store) that uses TokBox (essentially WebRTC), and it renders this bar already for iOS when backgrounded, but not Android.

Comment: iOS automatically provides that for any app that is performing the associate background task. It's not specific to any library you may or may not be using. It's a feature of iOS, not your app.

Comment: I understand that this is enforced by the iOS system. I'm looking for a solution for Android that produces the same effect. I am also aware that Android persistent notifications that live in the notification drawer can be used, but I'm wondering if a persistent bar can be rendered on Android that lives outside of the notification drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consistent way to indicate an ongoing phone call in **Android** is using a notification. The Android phone app also uses a notification in this scenario:

[image: Android In-Call Notification]

To prevent the user from dismissing this notification, you can use the `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` or `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` - see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

On **iOS**, you might want to set a specific `Audio Mode` and `Audio Category` to get the right status bar look.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_session_services/1618405-audio_session_modes
and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_session_services/1618427-audio_session_categories

Further, the `Background Audio` capability is required - otherwise, your Apps audio session will be stopped after moving it to the background.

To achieve an even more consistent user experience, you might want to integrate the iOS CallKit or the Android ConnectionService, see
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, is it possible in Android to render an "in progress" bar that lives outside of the notification drawer/shade *without* using ConnectionService? I want to notify the user that my app is using resources, but it doesn't make sense to treat it as a call.

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented in Android by using a notification and adding a flag FLAG_NO_CLEAR

[This is a link where this is explained pretty clearly](https://www.laurivan.com/android-make-your-notification-sticky/)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm specifically not looking for a persistent notification, but instead something that persists regardless of whether or not the notification drawer is pulled open.